# Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on a domain and $|f|=|g|$ then $f(z)=e^{i\theta}g(z)$ for some $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to use $h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ but I've got nothing else. Note that they are not entire, so I can't use Liouville's theorem.

Comment: what do you mean by you tried to use $h(z)=f(z)/g(z)$??

Comment: I tried to prove it is constant but failed

Comment: what is the probelm in using h=f/g?? Take this as a hint.. What could go wrong if you consider h=f/g??

Answer (score 1):

It follows from your assumption that the range of $h$ is a subset of $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\lvert z\rvert=1\}$. If $h$ was not constant, then by the open mapping theorem, the reang of $h$ would be an open subset of $S^1$. But the only subset of $S^1$ which is an open subset of $\mathbb C$ is the empty set. Since the range of $h$ cannot be empty, the conclusion is that $h$ is constant. So, for some $\theta\in\mathbb R$, we have $h(z)=e^{i\theta}$, for every $z$ in the domain of $h$.

Comment: Can g(z) be never zero?

Comment: Yes, it can. But then either $g$ is the null function, in which case the statement is trivial, or it is not. In this case, you remove from the domain the zeros of $g$ and what remains is still connected.

Comment: Yes, as zeros of a hol function are isolated, the domain minus those points is still connected.. I thought it needs to be mentioned.. :)